# using callback from delphi dll with c++

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, callback, function-pointers

I have to use a delphi dll which provides some callback procedures. If I use them with C# everything work's. If I use C++ the callbacks do not work.
In the delphi dll the callback is written like:

```pascal
procedure addConnectionCallBack(connectCallback: TConnectCallback);    StdCall;
begin
  initMyConnection();
  if assigned(MyConnection) then
  begin
    MyConnection.addConnectionCallBack(connectCallback);
  end;
end;
```

Everything works when using C#:

```cs
// make delegate
public delegate void ConnectionCallBack();

// define dll
[DllImport(_dll_name, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void addConnectionCallBack(ConnectionCallBack ccb);

// function with signature of ConnectionCallBack
private void showConnected() {
    Console.WriteLine("connected");
}

// address callback to dll  
public void start() {
    addConnectionCallBack(showConnected);
}
```

In C++ I can not solve it:

```cpp
typedef void (__stdcall *ConnectionCallBack)();
typedef void (__stdcall *addConnectionCallBack)(ConnectionCallBack);

addConnectionCallBack _addConnectionCallBack;

// !!! this should be called from delphi dll, but isn't !!!
void __stdcall showConnected() {
    std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
}
//auto showConnected = []()->void {std::cout << "connected" << std::endl; };

int main()
{
    LPCWSTR _dll_name = L"MyDelphi.dll";
    HINSTANCE _hModule = NULL;  
    _hModule = LoadLibrary( _dll_name);
    assert(_hModule != NULL);

    _addConnectionCallBack = (addConnectionCallBack) GetProcAddress(_hModule, "addConnectionCallBack");

    ConnectionCallBack conn = showConnected;
    _addConnectionCallBack(conn);

    // do some other dll calls which work and force the callback.   

    FreeLibrary(_hModule);
    return 0;
}
```

Other calls to the dll which return a string are working. Tried using function pointers in various ways or `std::function`/`std::bind` without luck.

Please can someone check my C++ code and give me a hint! I have no ideas any more.

Comment: *If I use C++ the callbacks do not work.* -- Please explain in better detail what you mean by "do not work".  The program crashes?  Some other function gets called?  No function gets called?

Comment: In the c++ solution the function showConnected() never gets called. In the C# it gets.

Comment: So the question now is this:  What is the Delphi code doing?  What is the value of that callback?  The C++ code is probably not being called because Delphi isn't calling it.  `if Assigned(connectedCallback) then` -- and what if this result is `false`?

Comment: I am not familiar with delphi. So the better question for me is, what makes the C# code so much different to the c++ code? Because with C# it works.

Comment: `C# != C++`.  That's why you have to look at the middleman, the Delphi code, to see what it actually did do.

Comment: A C# delegate used with PInvoke is marshaled using `stdcall` by default, unless you use the `UnmanagedFunctionPointer` attribute to specify a different calling convention. Your C++ code is *redefining* the existing `CALLBACK` macro to `PASCAL` which *may* be `__stdcall` depending on compiler, but you should not be redefining `CALLBACK` at all, it is already defined by the Win32 API. What is the **actual** declaration of `TConnectCallback` in the Delphi code? Assuming it is using `stdcall`, and you remove your manual `CALLBACK` definition, I see nothing else wrong with the C++ code...

Comment: ... assuming `_addConnectionCallBack` is not NULL, then the problem is likely inside the DLL itself.  Maybe you are not calling into it correctly to make it reach the point where it wants to call the callback. What function(s) does the DLL actually export that call the callback, and how are you calling those function(s) in C++ vs C#? One warning flag I see is `addConnectionCallBack()` is a method of the `TSocket` class, but that is not being exported directly. Is there a separate wrapper function being exported that uses `TSocket` internally?

Comment: @Remy In this case the C# is a clearer definition of the interface. Code looks fine. Asker needs to do more to show what is wrong.

Comment: The C++ code would be a lot cleaner if it used static linking instead of `LoadLibrary()`.

Comment: @Remy One might guess that the supplier of the DLL was unable to provide an import lib

Comment: C++ compilers provide tools for generating import libs for/from DLLs.

Comment: @Remy I removed the PASCAL, unfortunatelly not difference. I can provide more information in the next days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a Visual Studion Win32 Project template or rather modifing the C++ main function into:

`int CALLBACK WinMain( In HINSTANCE hInstance, In HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, In LPSTR     lpCmdLine, In int nCmdShow) {}`

This keeps the dll's process alive.

Thanks for all the help.